# how to get input value with typescript(put request )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I want to get input value and put them in json
but I don't know how to get input value in this case

if I tried document.querySelector("todo-text").value
It turns out to error.

```
const NewTodo: React.FC<NewTodoProps> = (props) => {
  /*   const textInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null); */
  const formData = new FormData();
  const photos = document.querySelector('input[type="text"][multiple]');

  const data = {
    word: document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("todo-text").value,
    meaning: document.getElementById("todo-meaning"),
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const body = JSON.stringify(data);
    debugger;
    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/vocas", {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      //mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      //cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      //credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "*/*",
      },
      //redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      //referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
      body: body, // 本文のデータ型は "Content-Type" ヘッダーと一致する必要があります
    });
    debugger;
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
    return;
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-control">
        <label htmlFor="todo-text">単語:</label>
        <input type="text" id="todo-text" />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="todo-meaning">意味:</label>
        <input type="text" id="todo-meaning" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">追加</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

in this case, how to get input value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use useState to get the capture the userinput

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const[toDoText,setToDoText] = useState("");
```

in input field add a onChange Event

```
    const handleInput = (event : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            let target = event.target;
            setToDoText((currentState) => {
                return target.value;
            })
        }
      <input type="text" id="todo-text" onChange={handleInput} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. however, i got another error! :<

Comment: when i add your code, i got  Cannot find name 'setuserState'. error and Parameter 'currentState' implicitly has an 'any' type. error